# Need to get desired result without UNION

Tags: mysql, select

I have table like,

```
id  | OpenDate             |  CloseDate
------------------------------------------------
1   | 2013-01-16 07:30:48  |  2013-01-16 10:49:48
2   | 2013-01-16 08:30:00  |  NULL
```

I needed to get combined result as below

```
 id | date                 |   type
 ---------------------------------
 1  | 2013-01-16 07:30:48  |  Open
 1  | 2013-01-16 10:49:48  |  Close
 2  | 2013-01-16 08:30:00  |  Open
```

Using UNION we can achieve this, but how to get the desired result without using UNION?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell it's impossible to get a MySQL result set as you propose without using a union.

The question reads more like a puzzle (homework) than a real programming problem - why would UNION not be available? Why would you want to present access to data directly from a generic tool like PHPMyAdmin or mysql command line client? Once you've got a layer of code on top implementing stuff like presentation and access control, it's trivial to do without using UNION - but probably a lot simpler with a UNION statement: Why are you asking?

**UPDATE**
I've got a solution to the problem of not using a UNION - but that makes it rather obvious that this is a homework / interview question.

**UPDATE2**
Since LearneR has posted (then deleted) another question *implying* he's not happy with the performance of a UNION query, this loks less likely to be a homework / interview question. But just for entertainment value I'll hold off on posting my solution till later to see if anyone else can solve the puzzle (hint: my solution should not improve the performance of the query at all - it's just an academic exercise in trying to get the desired result without using UNION).

**UPDATE3**

Nobody got it?

```
SELECT t.id
,        IF(rowmultiplier.id=1, t.opendate, t.closedate) AS `date`
,        IF(rowmultiplier.id=1, 'Open', 'Close') AS `type`
FROM yourtable t
,    (SELECT id
    FROM yourtable AS tablealias
    WHERE id IN (1,2) ) AS rowmultiplier
WHERE rowmultiplier.id=1
OR t.closedate IS NOT NULL;
```

(there's some scope for tuning this, in the absence of any sorting / filtering, then forcing a full table table scan of the outer query and an index lookup on the inner query could make it a lot faster than the union query).

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354828/how-to-get-combined-result-in-mysql-with-query-optimization

Comment: That's going to get closed as not a real question.

Comment: I am not asking for homework, am facing problem while using the UNION. It's slow down the site loading since table has more than 4000 rows. I have added EXPLAIN result in provided link. Please help me out this.

Comment: @LearneR: you don't like my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the case Statement
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

It could be something like (not tested)

```
select date,
    case time(formatted_timefield)
        when between '07:00:00' and '18:00:00'
        then 'open'
        else 'close'
    end case
```

So you can use multiple check like

```
select 
CASE WHEN 1=1 AND 2=2 THEN 'open' ELSE 'closed' END
from Table
```

So at all try something like

```
select
    date,
    CASE WHEN OpenDate < now() AND CloseDate > now() THEN 'open' ELSE 'closed' END
from
    table
```

Comment: this will return only a single row in the output for each row of input (and your column names don't match)

Comment: @LearneR maybe you can serve your sql snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` condition ...

```
SELECT 
      id, 
      OpenDate as Open_Date, 
      IF (CloseDate, 'close', 'open') as Close_Date, 
      IF (CloseDate, CloseDate, '') as type 
FROM table;
```

Comment: As with Michael's answer this only returns a single row of output per row of input.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you give us puzzle.
why you want to make query complex when there is UNION Keyword available.
if you give us a puzzle my answer is use 'UNION ALL'.